# golang recurisive reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to reflect recursively over a struct, printing out the type of each field.   Where a field is an slice of structs, I'd like to be able to 
identify the type held in the array and then reflect over that type.

Here is some sample code

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type child struct {
    Name *string
    Age  int
}

type Parent struct {
    Name     string
    Surname  *string
    Children []*child
    PetNames []string
}

func main() {

    typ := reflect.TypeOf(Parent{})
    log.Printf("This is a : %s", typ.Kind())

    for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {
        p := typ.Field(i)
        if !p.Anonymous {
            switch p.Type.Kind() {
            case reflect.Ptr:
                log.Printf("Ptr: %s is a type %s", p.Name, p.Type)
            case reflect.Slice:
                log.Printf("Slice: %s is a type %s", p.Name, p.Type)
                subtyp := p.Type.Elem()
                if subtyp.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                    subtyp = subtyp.Elem()
                }
                log.Printf("\tDereferenced Type%s", subtyp)
            default:
                log.Printf("Default: %s is a type %s", p.Name, p.Type)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
This is a : struct
Default: Name is a type string
Ptr: Surname is a type *string
Slice: Children is a type []*main.child
    Dereferenced Type main.child
Slice: PetNames is a type []string
    Dereferenced Type string
```

When I identify that a field type is a slice of pointers, I am able to infer the type by calling subtype.Elem().

The output is 'main.child'

If I then try to reflect child using

```
subSubType := reflect.TypeOf(subtyp)
log.Printf("%+v", subSubType)
```

I get the following:

```
 *reflect.rtype
```

How can I use the reflection API to iterate over the fields of the child struct?

Comment: Don't call `reflect.TypeOf(subtyp)`, `subtyp` is already of type `reflect.Type`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Th0uGACjwH this is just an example, i don't like the way i'm handling the field names but it's getting late here, so this'll hopefully point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
func printType(prefix string, t reflect.Type, visited map[reflect.Type]bool) {

    // Print the name of this type with opening ( for description.
    fmt.Printf("%s (", t)

    // Traverse elements, adding to description as we go.
elems:
    for {
        switch t.Kind() {
        case reflect.Ptr:
            fmt.Print("ptr to ")
        case reflect.Slice:
            fmt.Print("slice of ")
        case reflect.Array:
            fmt.Printf("array with %d elements of ", t.Len())
        default:
            break elems
        }
        t = t.Elem()
    }

    // Print the kind of the type and the closing ) of the description.
    // In the case of a struct, we print the names of the fields and recurse.
    switch t.Kind() {
    case reflect.Struct:
        fmt.Printf("struct with %d fields)\n", t.NumField())
        if visited[t] {
            // Don't blow up on recursive type definition.
            break
        }
        visited[t] = true
        prefix += "    "
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            f := t.Field(i)
            fmt.Print(prefix, f.Name, " ")
            printType(prefix, f.Type, visited)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%s)\n", t.Kind())
    }
}

func main() {
    printType("", reflect.TypeOf(Parent{}), make(map[reflect.Type]bool))
}
```

The output for Parent{} given the following types:

```
type child struct {
    Name *string
    Age  int
}

type Parent struct {
    Name     string
    Surname  *string
    Children []*child
    PetNames []string
    Parents  [2]*Parent
    child
}
```

is:

```
main.Parent (struct with 6 fields)
    Name string (string)
    Surname *string (ptr to string)
    Children []*main.child (slice of ptr to struct with 2 fields)
        Name *string (ptr to string)
        Age int (int)
    PetNames []string (slice of string)
    Parents [2]*main.Parent (array with 2 elements of ptr to struct with 6 fields)
    child main.child (struct with 2 fields)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/LEaanxYN2v)

Comment: Thanks this works.   If I wanted to pass a struct with values, is it possible to also extract the values for each field ? i.e.parent := Parent{Name: "Joe", Children: []*child{&child{Name: "Bobby", Age: 4,},},}   Then the output would print  "Name *string (ptr to string) (Bobby)"   ?

Comment: The code above works on types as asked in the question. The code for values will be very similar. Use fmt.Sprintf("%v", v) to print the values.