# iterate through map[string]interface{} recursively using reflect package

Tags: go, reflection

i just trying learn to use reflection, i wanna go througe each field in the map[string]interface{} this why i using
json.Unmarshal to interface{}.

```
func i2s(data interface{}, out interface{}) error {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(data).Kind())
    switch reflect.TypeOf(data).Kind() {
    case reflect.Map, reflect.Array, reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
        i2s(reflect.TypeOf(data).Elem(), out)

    case reflect.Struct:
        for i := 0; i < reflect.ValueOf(data).NumField(); i++ {
            f := reflect.TypeOf(data).Field(i)
            fmt.Println(f.Name, f.Type.Name())

            if f.Tag != "" {
                fmt.Println(f.Tag)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type Simple struct {
    ID       int
    Username string
    Active   bool
}

func main() {
    test := &Simple{
        ID:       42,
        Username: "dcandu",
        Active:   true,
    }

    jsonRaw, _ := json.Marshal(test)

    var tmpData interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(jsonRaw, &tmpData)

    result := new(Simple)
    i2s(tmpData, result)
}
```

When i run this code i get the infinite loop.
Please tell me where i'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: you are doing reflection of a reflected values recursively. `i2s(reflect.TypeOf(data).Elem()...` sends a reflect.Value, thus it is always a ptr. I dont understand what you are trying to achieve in the end, i can t tell more.

Comment: If you know the value is the output of json.Unmarshal to `interface{}`, then type assert your way through the structure. No reflection is needed.  If you want to recurse through a value of arbitrary types, then write the function in terms of reflect.Value, not reflect.Type. [This code may be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664320/golang-recursively-reflect-both-type-of-field-and-value#answer-47664689).